# System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0 when list is not empty

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have an apex code like that :

```
List<Campaign> campaigns = DataFactory.createCampaign();

    Contact contact = new Contact(/*some fields here*/);
    if(!campaigns.isEmpty()){
        DataFactory.createCampaignMember(campaigns[0], contact);
    }
```

If I put a `system.debug(campaings)` I retrieve 3 campaings, so my list `campaigns` is not empty. 
But when I run the code (it is in an apex test class) I got this error :

> System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

at the line `DataFactory.createCampaignMember(campaigns[0], contact);`

How can I resolve this error ?

EDIT :

Here is the method of the DataFactory :

```
public static CampaignMember createCampaignMember(Campaign campaign, Contact contact){
  List<Contact> idContact = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE FirstName=:contact.FirstName LIMIT 1];
  List<Campaign> idCampaign = [SELECT Id FROM Campaign WHERE Name=:campaign.Name LIMIT 1];
  CampaignMember campaignMember = new CampaignMember(ContactId=idContact.get(0).Id, CampaignId=idCampaign.get(0).Id);
  return campaignMember;
}
```

The error is indicated on the line `CampaignMember(ContactId=idContact.get(0).Id, CampaignId=idCampaign.get(0).Id);`

Comment: show full test class and full error message with mentioned line

Comment: this is a whole test method and the line is the one indicated in the question

Comment: looks like you have problem inside `DataFactory.createCampaignMember` method

Comment: I added the method from the DataFactory and the line indicated by the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `createCampaignMember` method you have `List<Contact> idContact = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE FirstName=:contact.FirstName LIMIT 1];` soql that queries Contact.

but from test class you don't insert such contact `Contact contact = new Contact(/*some fields here*/);` you need to insert this contact.

```
List<Campaign> campaigns = DataFactory.createCampaign();

Contact cont = new Contact(/*some fields here*/);
insert cont;
if(!campaigns.isEmpty()){
    DataFactory.createCampaignMember(campaigns[0], cont);
}
```

make sure that `List<Campaign> campaigns = DataFactory.createCampaign();` also inserts campaigns to DB